# Anchor image gets overlapped by toolbar when CollapsingToolbarLayout is collapsed

Tags: android, xml

I am using CollapsingToolbarLayout in one of my layouts, I anchored an image (id=event_logo) on AppBar layout;
[How it looks before collapsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQA43.png)

however, when CollapsingToolbarLayout is totally collapsed the Toolbar covers the image.
[How it looks after collapsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXKeL.png)

my xml code

```html
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="185dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/bgg" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/about_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/MyTheme1"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            
            .....

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/event_logo"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/barcode_scanner"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:contentDescription="event_logo"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />
```

Tested on Android 6.0

Any Idea why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers to this question...The trick to solve this issue is to set elevation to 20dp

Simply add elevation attribute to the anchored image

```html
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/event_logo"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:contentDescription="event_logo"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
```

note: attribute elevation is used only for API 21 and higher, that's why it's necessary to add targetApi lollipop

Comment: The minimum value that has to be set for elevation is 4dp. Below that, it starts overlapping the image.